# How do I tell if a Django QuerySet has been evaluated?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm creating a Django queryset by hand and want to just use the Django ORM to read the resulting querset.query SQL itself without hitting my DB.

I know Django quersets are lazy and I see all the ops that trigger a queryset being evaluated:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

But... what if I just want to verify my code is purely building the queryset guts but ISN'T evaluating and hitting my DB yet inadvertently?  Are there any attributes on the queryset object I can use to verify it hasn't been evaluated without actually evaluating it?

Comment: I have other uses for the SQL that the Django ORM creates than actually evaluating it immediately.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For querysets that use a `select` to return lists of model instances, like a basic filter or exclude, the `_result_cache` attribute is `None` if the queryset has not been evaluated, or a list of results if it has. The usual caveats about non-public attributes apply.

Note that printing a queryset - although the docs note calling `repr()` as an evaluation trigger - does not in fact evaluate the original queryset. Instead, internally the original queryset chains into a new one so that it can limit the amount of data printed without changing the limits of the original queryset. It's true that it evaluates a subset of the original queryset and therefore hits the DB, so that's another weakness of this approach if you're in fact trying to use it to monitor all DB traffic.

For other querysets (count, delete, etc) I'm not sure there is a simple way. Maybe watch your database logs, or run in `DEBUG` mode and check `connection.queries` as described here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running

Comment: actually, in django 3 this attribute is None even after evaluation

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav - how certain of that are you? I haven't spun up a Django 3 project to check, but from the source it sure looks like it's still used as it was in Django 2. EG https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L1320 to populate it, https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L261 for one example of the kind of call that evaluates and uses it.

Comment: I defined a queryset, which `_result_cache` attribute was None before evaluation. Then i forced evaluation like this: `print(qryset)`, which returned me the result. I checked this attribute again and it was still None

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav - ah, there's your problem. Try it using `len()` or `list()` or something instead of `print()`. `print` calls `__repr__`, which calls `list()` on a slice of the queryset. But slicing is implemented by - if the `_result_cache` is empty - chaining the original queryset into a new object, then modifying the limits and populating the `_result_cache` of the new copy. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L303 I'll update to note that this attribute is not modified when printing, since the docs list that as an evaluation trigger.